# Is it possible to adjust the width of the fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to adjust the width of the fullcalendar

I am placing the fullcalendar inside a container which is resizable . Can update the width of fullcalendar based on container width

Comment: Can u share the code ?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio says "A calendar is a block-level element that fills its entire avaiable width. ". So that should be the default behaviour, unless you've changed anything

Comment: No I haven't changed the default settings 
  {
                handleWindowResize  : true,
                expandRows          : true,
                height              : height,
                windowResize        : function(arg) {
                },
                headerToolbar       : {
                ..
                },
                navLinks : true, 
                businessHours : false, 
                editable : false,
                selectable : false,
                events : ev
            });

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css styles to the div containing the calendar.

```
<div id='calendar' style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

Or U can wrap it into another `div`

```
<div class="outer" style="width:80%;">
   <div id="calendar">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am already  doing that . it resizes the container but not the cal content

Comment: Without code it will be difficult to find problems. can u share it .

Answer (score 0):

The default size of various columns and grid in Full-Calendar is set to 817px. Changing them to 100% resolved the problem.

Following is the css which can be use.

```
.fc-col-header, .fc-scrollgrid-sync-table, .fc-daygrid-body.fc-daygrid-body-unbalanced.fc-daygrid-body-natural, .fc-daygrid-body.fc-daygrid-body-unbalanced, .fc-timegrid-body, .fc-timegrid-slots table, .fc-timegrid-cols table{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```